# Dropbox API file URL invalid

Tags: javascript, json, dropbox-api

I'm using a javascript Dropbox picker script that displays the Dropbox picker window that allows a user to select files and returns a list of selected files. Said script can be found here:

http://codingbin.com/jquery-cloud-storage-file-picker/

The picker I'm talking about is the standard Dropbox picker popup as seen below:

[image]

The JSON response is similar to below:

```
{ 
    isDir: false, 
    name: "test.txt", 
    bytes: 1600, 
    link: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/some-hash-here/test.txt", 
    id: "id:QPX-_Anj3-another-hash-here", 
    icon: "https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/icons64/page_white_text.png" 
}
```

Everything seems to be working for a while but after a few minutes, the link becomes invalid. I am selecting a file that is public shared , BTW.

Another issue is that the icon fields always returns the same image.

Anyone here came across this same problem? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: got a link to that plugin?

Comment: Thank for the reply. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for the Invalid link:**

If your using direct link of a file then it will `expire after four hours` which is mentioned here [Under Link Types](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser)

**Reason for the same icon:**

Icons are based on the file's extension, here you've chosen the `.txt` file so obviously icon might be same for all the text type files.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you suggest a way I can get a permanent link to the file? As you see, there is no other link to the file in the JSON reponse other than in the ``link`` field.

Comment: Also, even when picking an image file, the icon is still https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/icons64/page_white_text.png

Comment: Please refer this page for more detail
 [Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser)

Comment: The "preview" link type doesn't expire like the "direct" link type does. (The "preview" links can be manually revoked by the user though.)